# Casting a variable in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Separate file inside lib. No direct access to these types.

fileA.js

```
export class MyTypeASuper {
  moof: string
};
```

---

Separate file inside lib. No direct access to these types.

Imports fileA.js

fileB.js

```
export class MyTypeBSuper {
  foo: MyTypeASuper
};
```

---

Main lib file the my code imports

This imports fileA.js and fileB.js

index.js

```
export class MyTypeA extends MyTypeASuper {
  test() {}
};

export class MyTypeB extends MyTypeBSuper {
  test() {}
};
```

---

My code using the lib

I import index.js so have no access to the Super classes.

```
const test: MyTypeB = new MyTypeB();

const a:MyTypeA = (test.foo: MyTypeA);
```

All of this gives me a `Cannot cast 'test.foo' to 'MyTypeA' because 'MyTypeASuper' is incompatible with 'MyTypeA'` error.

[https://flow.org/try here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTBQIAgZQUwBwIYCcEBcYQGYEsA2HsA7AZ2wBMNdsAjcYCAOQHsIzskYBjVCBTzmMWIRULVAAtBGVAE84guljwwAggDoAVsTqgYADzhMkPTrgRCIAWRkAVOaqgBXeUggBvUBAgBbJk0wAXBDEqEhEAOagAL4A3KA6kLCIKOhK+BBEpBQQVLSQzKzsXDx8AhaiIpLE0vbakACS3obGwjj46lqKbTAAQpp1YPrNJmYW1nbyPU4u7p5YfkHj9irTMEjRcQn0lghEOTRp0pI+MhCcTNnYTUaoAxA24tjCV8Otyh3CCIRkh32dkEQKHp+johjczqNhEt5CoIPp0N8obZlqtXB4vOgQgAKACU7iiG3iYOMEPMSImvThegRZHJ9imzjWswxglQuPxhK2VlO52yjlIhHClUoNEU9Qy1xJgP0-WCLHECAAbhhCCxSoJhKJFBIMKjSUJBGodKBziQeJjUItkZMIABeCCEGAAd25FJ6uM2ppCvAC0NUdogWItakwC1dyxxmyAA)

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a super class to a child class directly.

Here's a simplification of what you are trying to do.

```js
class Base {}
class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}

// You CAN cast a child class to a super class
const a = new A()
const castBase: Base = a

// CANNOT cast a super class to a child class
const base = new Base()
const b: B = base // flow error that you are getting

// A runtime check must be performed to cast this,
// because the type system cannot guarantee type
// safety at compile time.
if (base instanceof B) {
  const bTested = base
} else {
  throw new Error('base is not an instance of B')
}
```

[try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8C+AoUkYEFoIA8AXBAOwBMZ4Ik1Nwo59izK5EUN0B6b6ATQD2AV2gBhHADlowSEWhgZACwCWIcjIYwighdAjCADggBOm7JkGkI8xQF5opBAHdoOABQBKS9fmyb1AgAXOw00A5g6Dx8eCbCpEQqALZIScI20ABGSMYmAGaCJikaOjJy0ESqEAA00VkIsulIlc0AnsZlpKSC8gDmwmAmYAkIbcZ1EGB5CEStCn6CSYZqzckIAHQ+GZkcDk6ugV7oKnnQ7jthKr7DwAiCp7CeKOjQMlbb4VmI6Kj4IGHIF4VJQmQSufbQACiJlBJncAHILkgVDBurZSNArjYbkh7nB4d5UEA)

Here, it is obvious that `base` is not an instance of either `A` or `B`. But since all child classes are also their super classes, you can cast a child class to a super class.

If you want to treat a superclass type as a child class type, you have to do a runtime check because the type system says that the instance could be the super class or ANY other base class. And since there is no way to know for sure, you have to check.